# ColumnModel Set Header error with mono 3.3.0

Tags: mono, ext.net, gridpanel

This is my asp.net GridPanel code with columnmodel id `ColumnModel3`

```
<South Split="true" Collapsible="true" CollapseMode="Mini">
                    <ext:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlMsgLst" Frame="true" Height="145" Title="消息列表" AutoScroll="true"
                        Collapsed="true">
                        <Content>
                            <ext:GridPanel ID="vehGridPnl" runat="server" StoreID="msgStore" StripeRows="true"
                                Frame="true" AutoHeight="true" AutoExpandColumn="Id" AutoScroll="true" EnableHdMenu="false">
                                <ColumnModel ID="ColumnModel3" runat="server">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <ext:Column ColumnID="Id" Header="ID" Width="80" DataIndex="Id" Hidden="false" />
                                        <ext:Column Header="消息内容" Width="180" DataIndex="Content">
                                            <Renderer Fn="change" />
                                        </ext:Column>
                                        <ext:Column Header="车牌号码" Width="90" DataIndex="CarPlateNo">
                                            <Renderer Fn="change" />
                                        </ext:Column>
                                        <ext:Column Header="设备ID" Width="90" DataIndex="DevID">
                                            <Renderer Fn="change" />
                                        </ext:Column>
                                        <ext:Column Header="经度" Width="80" DataIndex="Longitude">
                                            <Renderer Fn="change" />
                                        </ext:Column>
                                        <ext:Column Header="纬度" Width="80" DataIndex="Latitude">
                                            <Renderer Fn="change" />
                                        </ext:Column>
                                        <ext:Column Header="速度" Width="70" DataIndex="Speed">
                                            <Renderer Fn="change" />
                                        </ext:Column>
                                        <ext:Column Header="方向" Width="70" DataIndex="Angle">
                                            <Renderer Fn="change" />
                                        </ext:Column>
                                        <ext:Column Header="定位" Width="80" DataIndex="Location">
                                            <Renderer Fn="change" />
                                        </ext:Column>
                                        <ext:Column Header="时间" Width="150" DataIndex="Date">
                                            <Renderer Fn="change" />
                                        </ext:Column>
                                        <ext:Column Header="车辆状态" Width="300" DataIndex="Status">
                                            <Renderer Fn="change" />
                                        </ext:Column>
                                    </Columns>
                                </ColumnModel>
                                <SelectionModel>
                                    <ext:RowSelectionModel ID="RowSelectionModel3" SingleSelect="true" runat="server">
                                    </ext:RowSelectionModel>
                                </SelectionModel>
                            </ext:GridPanel>
                        </Content>
                    </ext:Panel>
                </South>
```

this is a Javascript, when page loaded, will automatically run this function

```
function ChangeTitle() {
   vehListPanel.setTitle(VehList_Title + "  :" + nVehCount.toString());
   btnVehDetails.setText(vVehDetails);

    pnlMsgLst.setTitle(pMsgList);

    ColumnModel3.setColumnHeader(1, pContent); 
    ColumnModel3.setColumnHeader(2, vVehNum);
    ColumnModel3.setColumnHeader(3, vDevID);

    ColumnModel3.setColumnHeader(4, pLongitude);
    ColumnModel3.setColumnHeader(5, pLatitude);
    ColumnModel3.setColumnHeader(6, pSpeed);

    ColumnModel3.setColumnHeader(7, pAngle);
    ColumnModel3.setColumnHeader(8, pLocate);
    ColumnModel3.setColumnHeader(9, pTime);

    ColumnModel3.setColumnHeader(10, pAlarmStatus);
}
```

This Function will change the `columnmodel3` header.
Unfortunately, this only work on IIS, when i m trying on my real server, it will return an Error

```
ReferenceError: ColumnModel3 is not defined

ColumnModel3.setColumnHeader(1, pContent);
```

is this a bug? or what? any other way to change the column header ?

Server are using mono3.3.0,xsp4 and ext.net version is 1.3.0
P/S : other components like button,label are working proper with `SetText` and `SetTitle`. just ColumnModel having the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since, the way can't work, i m trying on firebug to change the header, and finally i get the way to change the header from firebug with javascript like this

```
vehColModel = parent.frames["StatisticFrm0_IFrame"].vehGrid.colModel

vehColModel.setColumnHeader(3, vVehNum);
vehColModel.setColumnHeader(4, vDevID);
```